# Should I wait until after my doctoral disputation to apply for a job in the industry?

Tags: applications, degree

I will submit my Ph.D. thesis in September and hopefully have my disputation in January. I studied computer science and my current research fund would be finished by April, and I'm thinking about joining the industry as a data scientist or something similar.

Although I prefer to find a job as soon as possible, I wonder if it's better to wait for my disputation and apply for jobs while holding the doctorate title, or should I apply as soon as I submit my thesis?

Of course if one reads my CV carefully would come to the conclusion that I'd receive my degree in a few months, but I Wonder how much is the immediate gain of that title in the first impression they get from my applications especially when they want quickly shortlist candidates.

Answer (score 7):

Applying and interviewing can take months before you are given an offer.

In my case I started applying 9 months before defending my thesis, and had interviews going on for a certain position for months: the first over the phone one was in April and I ended up doing the face to face interview in September, two days after my defense.

Other PhD students of my same year even found a job one year before defending the thesis, and started working while finishing it.

Just make clear what is your expected availability date when you apply.

Answer (score 2):

You can start applying for open positions right away, just make sure that you have your CV updated properly at proper time. In other words, one should not need to be looking hard to find whether you are about to obtain the degree or already holding it. Make it clear upfront.

If nothing else, you'll gain experience. All the best.

Comment: In my education background part in my CV I mention that i'm expected to receive my degree in xx.2021. is it good enough? Should I somehow add it to the header part or somewhere else?!

Comment: @Bob It should be good. If you use a header for your CV, you can also mention it there, otherwise OK. Also, this should be in your bio, starting of the CV so that no one has to waste time till they reach the educational qualification part.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should apply, there is no benefit to waiting after just as long as the job search doesn't affect your usual work. Remember that companies hire all year around depending on their need, and if companies want to hire you they'll be fine waiting for four months for you to start, and you'll gain a lot of experience to what the job market is like right now around you. Job searching also takes a long time so the earlier you start the better. Also just to add on if you're worried about completing the degree before applying, I think its the norm for students to look for jobs before completing their degree during their penultimate and final year.